# How to ask current company if they want to hire me and how to handle different company offer

Tags: interviewing, job-offer, internship

I'm currently doing an internship in a company. Supposedly, after finishing the internship they are going to hire me, that's what the told me when I first had the interview, but the thing is that I have no physical proof of that.

In the meantime, I have a friend that told me that in their company were looking for somebody and If I wanted them to recommend me. I was not especially interested, but I said yes anyways, because I didn't want to close any doors.

The thing is that if I'm offered a job after the internship in my current company, I would prefer to stay here rather than change to the other (if they also wanted to hire me), but since I don't know 100% for sure if they will hire me, I don't want to reject the other offer (if they make me one).

I haven't had the interview with the other company yet, I'm delaying it since I don't really know what to do.

I'm planning to have the interview anyways and I actually have two questions, depending on the possible scenarios:

- In the case that I receive the other company's offer before knowing if they want to hire me in my current company, it would be ok to ask hr if they plan to hire me? If it is, how should approach the issue?
- If they actually want to hire me, and the other company also wants to hire me, how should I reject the offer from the other company?

Note: The question title might be confusing, I didn't really know how to title it, so I if anyone can improve it I welcome edits.

Comment: [Is it okay to ask for a job guarantee at a company after an internship?](//workplace.stackexchange.com/q/99662) [What is the best protocol for courteously declining a job offer?](//workplace.stackexchange.com/q/1430) [Turning down a job offer professionally.](//workplace.stackexchange.com/q/5844)

Answer (score 2):

> In the case that I receive the other company's offer before knowing if
>   they want to hire me in my current company, it would be ok to ask hhrr
>   if they plan to hire me? If it is, how should approach the issue?

Take the interview at the other company and proceed until the conclusion of the interview process.  At the moment, you do not have a guarantee of a permanent position from either company.

> If they actually want to hire me, and the other company also wants to
>   hire me, how should I reject the offer from the other company?

If you get an offer, then take that to the company you are interning at, and ask them if they would be willing to take you on as a permanent employee.  If the answer is no, at least you have **a permanent job**.

This is the only logical way I see to get a win out of your scenario, otherwise you risk potentially having nothing at the end of this.

Good luck!